# Only Calling Alloc on the Object

Tags: objective-c

I am using the following code to initialize my object:

```
 Spaceship *spaceship = [Spaceship alloc];

    [spaceship fire];
```

The fire method is getting invoked and it seems to be working fine. My question is that how is it working when I have not used the init method to initialize the object.

Comment: Have `fire` do an `NSLog()` of an `NSString` that you allocate in your `init` method and see what happens...

Comment: Actually the above probably won't do anything as messages to `nil` get swallowed, and your un-inited `NSString` is probably `nil`...but JeremyP and Black Frog are correct, don't rely on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your `-init` method actually do?  If you don't have one, I'll let you into a secret: in the *current* implementation of the run time, `NSObject`'s `-init` is just about a no-op, so forgetting to send `-init` to an object with no `-init` method of its ownis not a huge disaster.  You shouldn't rely on that though and you should be sending `-init` to your objects.

Answer (score 2):

The fire method will work because objective-c just pass the message to the receiver. But any initialization that you do in your init is not executed.